# Replace html text with dynamic value Java

Tags: java, jsf-2

How to replace  HREF value with dynamic value in java

```
  <a href=\"http://www.example.com\"> with <a href=\ outcome \">
```

where String outcome ="home\login.jsf"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use either EL (like JSTL)  render the string there.

Example JSTL is:

```
<a href=#{outcome}> with <a href=\ outcome \">
```

Answer (score 1):

There are different types of outcomes possible. If you're using plain HTML or components such as h:outputLink and h:link, the EL expressions will be interpreted while rendering the page instead of being 100% dynamic.

```
<h:link outcome="#{bean.link}" value="I go to a page!"/>
```

Will result in an `<a>` tag with the link specified by `#{bean.link}` as its href.

Also, in JSF 2.x you can use conditional navigation in your defiend rules by adding an if clause referencing a bean attribute:

```
<navigation-rule>
    <from-view-id>index.xhtml</from-view-id>
    <navigation-case>
        <from-outcome>logIn</from-outcome>
        <if>#{sessionBean.sessionActive}</if>
        <to-view-id>userDashboard.xhtml</to-view-id>
        <else if>#{sessionBean.rejectedUser}</else if>
            <to-view-id>index.xhtml</to-view-id>
        <else>
            <to-view-id>register.xhtml</to-view-id>
    </navigation-case>
</navigation-rule>
```

On the other hand, elements like h:commandButton and h:commandLink have an action attribute that references a method with return type String or void. If the method return String then you can return "#" or a navigation rule, either implicit navigation or a configured rule:

```
<h:commandLink value="Log In" action="#{bean.logIn}"/>
```

The logIn method will be invoked from your Bean:

```
public String logIn() {
    //Your login logic
    if(userIsLoggedIn) {
        return "userDashboard"; //Implicit navigation
    } else {
        return "index"; //Implicit navigation
    }
}
```

Implicit navigation (JSF 2.x) will let you navigate between pages in the same folder by returning the name of the page. For example, returning `index` will send the user to `index.jsf`.

Answer (score 0):

Replace 'a' tag with 'h:commandLink' tag.And bind value and action as you like.

```
  <h:commandLink value="#{..}" action="#{yourBean.yourMethod()}"/>
```